# Array of parameters in a JSONObject using JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am trying to have this exact JSON syntax but can't get to it:

```
{
    "sun":"yellow",
    "vegetables":[{
        "apple":"red",
        "banana":"yellow",
        "melon":"orange"
    }]
}
```

The closest I can get is:

```
{
    "sun":"yellow",
    "vegetables":["{
        "apple":"red",
        "banana":"yellow",
        "melon":"orange"
    "]}
}
```

This is what I am doing:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("sun","yellow");

ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("apple","red");
params.put("banana","yellow");
params.put("melon","orange");

test.add(params);
json.put("fruits",test);
```

I can't figure it out, am I missing something?

Comment: "The closest I can get is:" version isn't even valid JSON!  Also, you put in "fruits" so how does it come out "vegetables"?  Whatever JSON parser you are using is awesome ;)  Please run your application again and provide us with the real output rather than what you typed out! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be like this -

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("sun","yellow");

JSONArray veg = new JSONArray();
JSONObject vegData = new JSONObject();
vegData.put("apple","red");
vegData.put("banana","yellow");
vegData.put("melon","orange");

veg.put(vegData);   

json.put("vegetables",veg);
```

I am using `Jettison`. You can find details [here](http://jettison.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Looks like you put your answer just a bit ahead of me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do nesting?  Some examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

```
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();
JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
JSONArray  array = new JSONArray();

outer.put("sun", "yellow");
array.put("apple", "red");
array.put("bannanna", "yellow");
array.put("melon", "orange");

inner.put(array);

outer.put("Vegtables":inner);
```